# Magento 2 - The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only

Tags: magento2.4, permissions, setup-di-compile

I  got this issue after running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

```
$ bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interceptors generation... 4/9 [============>---------------]  44% 16 secs 300.0 MiB
In Generator.php line 139:
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  Class Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\Context does not exist                                                                                                                                         
  Class Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after ru  
  nning the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated cl  
  ass object to the signature of the related construct method, only.                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                        

setup:di:compile
```

I did many tries already, first, I changed the permission of `var`, `generated` and `pub` to 777 (by `chmod -R 777 var generated pub`), but it still doesn't work. I checked the `/generated/code` permission after the fail, it was changed to `drwxrwxr-x` as follows:

```
$ ls -al generated/           
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  3 mgt www-data 4096 Aug 26 06:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 mgt www-data 4096 Aug 26 03:55 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 mgt www-data  126 Aug 26 03:55 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x 16 mgt mgt      4096 Aug 26 06:47 code
```

Then, I generated a new Magento2 project, but `bin/magento setup:di:compile` still returns the error.

What should I do next?

Version:
Magento  2.4.0

Comment: find this in your project "Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\Context"

Comment: this causes issue

Comment: Check if the Namespace of the class "Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\Context" is correct, and then check if the class corresponds with the one declared inside: "Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\Index\Interceptor"

Comment: I fixed the Context namespace in `Dmajor\PopupDemo\Controller\Test\` and it works now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of tinkering, I've finally found a solution.

1. Delete these folders: `generated` and `var`
2. Run these commands

```bash
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

After this, if the store is still broken add permissions to the `var/cache` folder